# Order by and then Concat

Tags: mysql, sorting, concat

I have a table `table1` like:

```
col1  col2

A1    A2
A1    B1
A1    B2
A2    A1
A2    B1
A2    B2
B1    A1
B1    A2
B1    B2
B2    A1
B2    A2
B2    B1
```

I need to concat `col1` and `col2` such a way that it should be sorted first.

Expected result:

```
col1  col2  ConcatResult

A1    A2    A1-A2
A1    B1    A1-B1
A1    B2    A1-B2
A2    A1    A1-A2
A2    B1    A2-B1
A2    B2    A2-B2
B1    A1    A1-B1
B1    A2    A2-B1
B1    B2    B1-B2
B2    A1    A1-B2
B2    A2    A2-B2
B2    B1    B1-B2
```

One more requirement: if possible, I would like to select the distinct from `ConcatResult` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       CONCAT(LEAST(col1, col2), '-', 
              GREATEST(col1, col2)) concat_result
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY concat_result
```

Output:

```
| COL1 | COL2 | CONCAT_RESULT |
|------|------|---------------|
|   A1 |   A2 |         A1-A2 |
|   A2 |   A1 |         A1-A2 |
|   B1 |   A1 |         A1-B1 |
|   A1 |   B1 |         A1-B1 |
|   A1 |   B2 |         A1-B2 |
|   B2 |   A1 |         A1-B2 |
|   A2 |   B1 |         A2-B1 |
|   B1 |   A2 |         A2-B1 |
|   A2 |   B2 |         A2-B2 |
|   B2 |   A2 |         A2-B2 |
|   B1 |   B2 |         B1-B2 |
|   B2 |   B1 |         B1-B2 |
```

To get distinct values from concatenated result

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CONCAT(LEAST(col1, col2), '-', 
              GREATEST(col1, col2)) concat_result
  FROM table1
 ORDER BY concat_result
```

Output:

```
| CONCAT_RESULT |
|---------------|
|         A1-A2 |
|         A1-B1 |
|         A1-B2 |
|         A2-B1 |
|         A2-B2 |
|         B1-B2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4353d/3)** demo

Answer (score 1):

Might be done with [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) expression.

Also MySQL allows to compare string binary representations with `<`, `>` and `=` operators. Another possibility is [`STRCMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#function_strcmp) function.

```
SELECT
    `col1`,
    `col2`,
    CASE
        WHEN `col1` > `col2` THEN CONCAT_WS('-', `col2`, `col1`)
        WHEN `col1` < `col2` THEN CONCAT_WS('-', `col1`, `col2`)
    END as `result`
FROM
    -- replace bottom part with table name.
    -- I've used UNION ALL for debugging.
    (
        SELECT 'A1' as `col1`, 'A2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A1' as `col1`, 'B1' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A1' as `col1`, 'B2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A2' as `col1`, 'A1' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A2' as `col1`, 'B1' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'A2' as `col1`, 'B2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B1' as `col1`, 'A1' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B1' as `col1`, 'A2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B1' as `col1`, 'B2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B2' as `col1`, 'A1' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B2' as `col1`, 'A2' as `col2` UNION ALL
        SELECT 'B2' as `col1`, 'B1' as `col2`
    ) `sub`
```

Result:

```
col1 col2 result
----------------
A1   A2   A1-A2
A1   B1   A1-B1
A1   B2   A1-B2
A2   A1   A1-A2
A2   B1   A2-B1
A2   B2   A2-B2
B1   A1   A1-B1
B1   A2   A2-B1
B1   B2   B1-B2
B2   A1   A1-B2
B2   A2   A2-B2
B2   B1   B1-B2
```

For `DISTINCT` case, it would be needed to exclude `col1` and `col2` from `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN `col1` > `col2` THEN CONCAT_WS('-', `col2`, `col1`)
        WHEN `col1` < `col2` THEN CONCAT_WS('-', `col1`, `col2`)
    END as `result`
FROM
    `YourTable`;
```

Result:

```
result
------
A1-A2
A1-B1
A1-B2
A2-B1
A2-B2
B1-B2
```